# Not getting results from function that makes API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a React app that uses Google Places API. I'm having trouble getting results from my function that makes the call to Google API -- I think because the API call is an async one.

I created a file that contains all Google Places functions that look like this:

```
const googlePlacesAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

const callbackGetAddressQueryPredictions = (predictions, status) => {

    if(status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) return null;
    return predictions;
}

export const googlePlacesAutoComplete = (keyword) => {

    googlePlacesAutocomplete.getQueryPredictions({input: keyword}, callbackGetAddressQueryPredictions);
}
```

In my React component, I import the googlePlacesAutoComplete() function like so:

```
import {googlePlacesAutoComplete} from '../googlePlaces';
```

I'm testing this with the following call in my React component but not getting anything.

```
onChangeAddress(event) {  
     const suggestions = googlePlacesAutoComplete("123 Main Street");
}
```

I'm sure I'm making a basic error due to my limited JS/ES2015 knowledge. Where am I going wrong?

UPDATE: 
I tried returning results from the googlePlacesAutoComplete() function -- though it was an ugly kludge, just wanted to see if that's the issue. This is what I tried:

```
const googlePlacesAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
let suggestions = [];

const callbackGetAddressQueryPredictions = (predictions, status) => {

  if(status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
     suggestions = predictions;
  }
}

export const googlePlacesAutoComplete = (keyword) => {

   googlePlacesAutocomplete.getQueryPredictions({input: keyword}, callbackGetAddressQueryPredictions);
   return suggestions;
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything in the `googlePlacesAutoComplete` function.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Tried what​‌​‌?​‌​

Comment: Tried returning the results from googlePlacesAutoComplete function. See my update in original post.

Comment: Uh, no, that's not how callbacks work. Read the duplicate target question again.